# UIAlertControllerにリスト（PickerかTableView）を追加する方法

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

こんにちは。
iOSアプリをObjective-cで開発しています。

ポップアップダイアログを表示させ、テキスト入力と、リストから項目を選択できるUIを追加したいです。

UIAlertControllerを使用し、「addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler」を使って、テキスト入力をさせることはできたのですが、リストを追加する方法がわかりません。

リストは、pickerでもTableViewでもどちらでも構わないのですが・・・。

どなたか、参考になる情報、ヒントなどをいただけないでしょうか・・・。

Answer (score 1):

通常・・・かはわかりませんが、このようなケースでご自身でUIViewControllerのサブクラスを作成します。
ご承知かもしれませんがUIAlertControllerもUIViewControllerベースです。

ポイントは、

- viewの背景色をclearにしポップアップダイアログのように見せる
- iOS 8以降、modalPresentationStyleをUIModalPresentationOverCurrentContextにし、背面のビューコントローラが映るようにする
- UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegateプロトコルを採用するオブジェクトをtransitioningDelegateにセットし、ポップアップのようなトランジションをさせる

  - そのデリゲートメソッドでUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioningプロトコルを採用するオブジェクトを返す
- 画面回転に関するイニチアシブに注意する（ナビゲーションコントローラを噛ませばそちら優先ですし、モーダル表示がこのビューコントローラ単体であればそれになりますが、背面の設定に追随するなど色々あるでしょう。ビューコントローラベースになってからアラート表示中でも回転するようになりましたが、iOS 6以前では回転しませんでした）

です。
ビューコントローラのview以下のデザインなどはストーリーボードで通常通り行えます。このように作成したビューコントローラをいつも通りpresent...するだけです。

おそらく、ほとんどの作業はビューコントローラの作成と変わりません。UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegateとUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioningのみ、学習が必要になると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。やはり、自分で作成するのが早いのですね。